# "no matching function for call to" function call on object

Tags: c++, g++

I am having an issue where every spot where I make a function call, such as `item.GetName()`, on an item in the `vector<ItemToPurchase> items` , I get the error message: `no matching function for call to vector<ItemToPurchase,__default_alloc_template<false,0> >::at (int &)` I've been looking all over and don't even uderstand what the "no matching function for call to" even means.

Example g++ message

```
ShoppingCart.cpp: In method `bool ShoppingCart::CheckCartForItem(class 
string)':
ShoppingCart.cpp:22: no matching function for call to 
`vector<ItemToPurchase,__default_alloc_template<false,0> >::at (int &)'
```

ShoppingCart.h:

```
#ifndef SHOPPINGCART_H
#define SHOPPINGCART_H

#include "ItemToPurchase.h"
#include <vector>

class ShoppingCart
{
public:
    ShoppingCart(string customerName = "none", string dateCreated = "January 1, 2016");
    *other functions*
    bool CheckCartForItem(string itemName);
    void AddItemToCart(ItemToPurchase item);
    *more functions*
private:
    *other variables*
    std::vector<ItemToPurchase> items;
};
#endif
```

ShoppingCart.cpp

```
#include "ShoppingCart.h"
#include <iostream>

ShoppingCart::ShoppingCart(string customerName, string dateCreated)
{
    this->customerName = customerName;
    this->dateCreated = dateCreated;
}

bool ShoppingCart::CheckCartForItem(string itemName)
{
    if (items.size() == 0) //if cart is empty
        return false;

    for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++)
    {
        if (items.at(i).GetName() == itemName) //<- Problem here
            return true;
    }

    return false;
 }

void ShoppingCart::AddItemToCart(ItemToPurchase item) 
{   
    if (CheckCartForItem(item.GetName()) == false) //if item not in cart
        items.push_back(item);
    else
        cout << "Item is already in cart. Nothing added." << endl;
}
```

ItemToPurchase.h

```
#ifndef ITEMTOPURCHASE_H
#define ITEMTOPURCHASE_H

#include <string>
using namespace std;

class ItemToPurchase
{
public:
    ItemToPurchase(string name = "none", string description = "none", double 
price = 0.0, int quantity = 0);
    void SetName(string);
    string GetName();
    *other functions*
private:
    string itemName;
    *other variables*
};

#endif // ITEMTOPURCHASE_H
```

ItemToPurchase.cpp

```
#include "ItemToPurchase.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>


ItemToPurchase::ItemToPurchase(string name, string description, double 
price, int quantity)
{
    itemName = name;
    itemDescription = description;
    itemPrice = price;
    itemQuantity = quantity;
}

void ItemToPurchase::SetName(string name){ itemName = name; }

string ItemToPurchase::GetName() { return itemName; }
```

Comment: A [mcve] would be very useful here.

Answer (score 0):

Since in this case you don't use the index variable, you can iterate with a [range-based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for):

```
for (auto& item : items) {
    if (item.GetName() == itemName) {
        [...]
```

[`std::vector:at`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/at/) expects a `std::vector::size_type` (which is typically defined as `std::size_t`). Changing the type of  `i` should make it compatible when using the index-based accessor:

```
for (std::vector<ItemToPurchase>::size_type i = 0; i < items.size(); ++i) {
    if (items.at(i).GetName() == itemName) {
        [...]
```

Comment: Tried it, but I still get the exact same message

Comment: It's the exact same message

Comment: 'ShoppingCart.cpp: In method bool ShoppingCart::CheckCartForItem(class string):
ShoppingCart.cpp:22: no matching function for call to vector<ItemToPurchase,__default_alloc_template<false,0> >::at (unsigned int &)'

Comment: But I'm just using the standard namespace vector, so I don't see how it wouldn't be following the current standard

Comment: So how exactly would I change it to `std::vector::size_type`?

Comment: I don't think it has to do with the for loop. This is the output: `ShoppingCart.cpp: In method bool ShoppingCart::CheckCartForItem(class string)':
ShoppingCart.cpp:21: no matching function for call to vector<ItemToPurchase,__default_alloc_template<false,0> >::at (size_t &)'`

Comment: Ok great. So the range-based loop caused that message to go away, but there's still another unresolved message: `ShoppingCart.cpp:30: request for member GetName in item, which is of non-aggregate type int
ShoppingCart.cpp:31: no matching function for call to vector<ItemToPurchase,__default_alloc_template<false,0> >::push_back (int &)` This makes me think there's a problem with my vector and the ItemToPurchase. Every place I make a call to a method on the object, I get some kind of message like that

Comment: I was able to compile your files using gcc 4.8.2. However I commented your *other variables* and *other functions* Also I removed <iomanip> did not see any use for it. If you care to provide those hidden variables/functions as well (of course with sensitive info masked) I can give it a try.